# What are the steps to connect to an android device using adb?

Tags: android, adb, remote-access, remote-debugging

I have been trying to connect my android device using adb but failed. I have enabled developer options and also enabled USB debugging ? Am I missing anything here? I have tried to connect using ghost framework too but dn't work. Could anybody pls suggest ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what error are you getting ? ...

```
Connect your Android device to the computer with a USB cable
The USB mode must be PTP in order for ADB to work. You can usually change this from 
the notification shade
Make sure to allow USB debugging if a pop-up appears
Open the platform-tools folder on your computer
Shift+Right Click and select Open command prompt here
Type adb devices and hit Enter
You should see a list of attached devices
Now you can enter ADB commands!
```